# Center align leading icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to align hint text and leading icon in  the center, like shown here:
[image: Center aligned icon and hint]

When I add a leading icon, and centre align decoration that is what I get. I need the icon to be in the centre as well.

[image: Leading icon is still left aligned]

Edit: Current code

```
TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Type something',
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)
    )
  ),
```

Comment: You need to share the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a widget for your case: `IntrinsicWidth`. This widget is used to size its child to the child's intrinsic width.

**Output**

[image]

**Full code:**

```
class CenteredTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CenteredTextField({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CenteredTextFieldState createState() => _CenteredTextFieldState();
}

class _CenteredTextFieldState extends State<CenteredTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 40.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 50.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.4),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.orange,
            width: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: IntrinsicWidth(
            child: TextField(
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                hintText: 'Type verse address',
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```